# How to get an image on full screen after tapping on it?

Tags: flutter

I am using the `Carousel Widget` to display images. I want to add a functionality where the user gets an image  on full screen after tapping on any of the image and also adding zoom in functionality might help.
As images to be displayed on a tap is specific each image I am not sure how `onTap` functionality of  `GuestureDetector` needs to be used here.

Here is my code:

```
Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              getAppBarUI(),
              ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 200.0,
                    width: 600.0,
                    child: Carousel(
                      images: [
                        Image.asset('assets/hotel/hotel_1.png'),
                        Image.asset('assets/hotel/hotel_1.png'),
                        Image.asset('assets/hotel/hotel_1.png'),
                      ],
                      animationDuration: Duration(minutes: 10),
                      dotSize: 2.0,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Each single detail will help. Thank You.

Comment: Make a new screen that accepts an argument, then using onTap push the screen

Answer (score 0):

in pubspec.yaml use below package for zooming and viewing the image in full screen.

> [photo_view: ^0.11.1](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view/example)

It may help you for more

```
class FullPhoto extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;

  FullPhoto({Key key, @required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'FULL PHOTO',
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FullPhotoScreen(url: url),
    );
  }
}

class FullPhotoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;

  FullPhotoScreen({Key key, @required this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => FullPhotoScreenState(url: url);
}

class FullPhotoScreenState extends State<FullPhotoScreen> {
  final String url;

  FullPhotoScreenState({Key key, @required this.url});

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: PhotoView(imageProvider: AssetImage(url)));
  }
}
```